# Status bar is showing when keyboard appears

Tags: java, android

I have created a simple app with an editText and a Button. I have set the status bar to be hidden in the app but by the time I tap on the editText, the keyboard appears, the status bar shows and the editText & Button move some pixels down. 
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: if you can show the code

Answer (score 0):

do it manually write this code on **onCreate above setContentView**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```